# Javascript Regex to filter String

Tags: javascript, regex

I need Regex to filter string to fit with the following conditions :

- The total length of the string cannot exceed 300 characters.
- The string cannot contain more than 4 hashtags.
- The string cannot contain more than 1 URL.
- The string cannot consist of all capital letters.

**Example Valid Text :**

> Developers trust #StackOverflow to help solve #coding problems and use
>   Stack Overflow Careers to find job opportunities. Please visit
>   https://stackoverflow.com/

**Example Invalid Text :**

> Developers trust #StackOverflow to help solve #coding problems and use
>   Stack Overflow Careers to find job opportunities. Please visit
>   https://stackoverflow.com/ or https://stackoverflow.com/company/about

Invalid string above because there are containing two URL.

Any help would be appreciated and thank you very much :)

Comment: Defined what an "URL" is.

Comment: @anshul-rai : Nope :( because I don't know much about regex

Comment: @derek-朕會功夫 : any URL...

Comment: @PeterChimp Well what do you mean by an URL?

Comment: @derek-朕會功夫 you can see on example Valid / Invalid string above...

Comment: Is `google.com` a valid URL? What about `8.8.4.4:80`?

Comment: @derek-朕會功夫 : Ok let's say All string that starting with http:// or https:// are marked as URL.

Comment: I believe the solution should be clear now. Break it into 4 regex's. For the url one, do a match and check how many there are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think [this](https://regex101.com/r/xB6xS4/5) will help you

```
^(?!^([^#]*#[^#]*){5,}$)(?!(.*http(s{0,1}):\/\/){2,})(?=.*[a-z]).{0,300}$
```

- `(?!^([^#]*#[^#]*){5,}$)` this will ensure that string should not contain more then 4 #
- `(?!(.*http(s{0,1}):\/\/){2,})` this will ensure that string should not contain more then 2 url
- `(?=.*[a-z])` this will ensure that string should contain at least 1 lower case letter
- `.{0,300}` this will ensure that string should contain not more then 300 charter

Comment: I would use `str.length<=300` instead of regex by checking the length. I think trying to do everything in a single regex is anti-pattern.